# TemplateDoesNotExist, Django has the good path but can't open the file

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my Django project : the Templates engines search at the good path but they don't find it... I tried everything :/
I think my settings.py file is ok :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'public',
]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and here my view code :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def enregistrement(request):
     return render(request, 'public/register.html')
```

I put my register.html in C:\SitePetitDejs\public\templates\public (yes the path is strange but it symplifies the problem)

And, when I go on http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/register I have "TemplateDoesNotExist at /public/register" error

The strangest thing is that the engines search at the good path :

- django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\SitePetitDejs\templates\public\register.html (Source does not exist)
- django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\public\register.html (Source does not exist)
- django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\public\register.html (Source does not exist)
- **django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\SitePetitDejs\public\templates\public\register.html (Source does not exist)**

Very blur behavior from the engines...
Maybe they don't have the permissions ? (The file is readable...)
I don't know how to solve this problem, I hope will be able to help me :)
Thankss

Comment: Please update the question and add your view code.

Comment: Is your actual template in `C:\SitePetitDejs\public\templates\public\register.html` or `C:\SitePetitDejs\public\templates\public\public\register.html`?

Comment: My template is in C:\SitePetitDejs\public\templates\public\register.html